# Understanding the "physical significance" of Tr$(A^{-1}B)<1$ for $A,B$ positive definite trace n matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be positive definite, $n\times n$ matrices, such that $\frac1n\operatorname{tr}(A)=\frac1n\operatorname{tr}(B)=1$.

Consider the situation where $$\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}B)<1.$$

**My question is:** physically, what does this mean?

If $A=UDU^T$ and $B=U\Sigma U^T$ were simultaneously diagonalizable, this would mean that 
$$\frac1n\sum_{1}^n\frac{\sigma_i}{d_i}<1,$$

so that the average quotient of eigenvalues is less than 1. I believe this is equivalent to the energy of $B$ concentrating in the same places as $A$. (Am I missing the best way of interpreting this case?)

What about the general case? Does this tell us anything about the relationship between the eigenstructure of $B$ and $A$? My intuition is that this would mean that $B$ correlates weakly with the weakest eigenspaces of $A$, and therefore most of the energy of $B$ concentrates on the dominant eigenspaces of $A$.

Can this be made more rigorous? I would love to read a good exposition of some of the subtleties here.

Comment: May I ask you in which framework you have met this condition $Tr(A^{-1}B)<1$ ? It's very new for me.

Comment: Look at page 6 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.01245.pdf

Comment: Thanks. One more question with a probable answer "yes" :  do you assume the eigenvalues are ranked in the order of their indices in both cases ?

Comment: Perhaps I confused you with the way I wrote the expression in the case that they are simultaneously diagonalizable. The equation I wrote in terms of the eigenvalues of A and B is perhaps deceptive. In the case that both are diagonal you shouldn't assume that the eigenvalues of both are in the same order.

Comment: How can $A,B$ be trace-$1$ matrices if their trace is $n$?

Comment: I corrected it. The title was incorrect, the text was correct: notice the normalization by 1/n.

Comment: Exactly. The normalization says the trace is $n$.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful or not, but since $A,B$ are PSD, $\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}B)$ is the trace norm (a.k.a. nuclear norm) of $A^{-1}B$. So, when it is smaller than $1$, $A^{-1}B$ is a contraction with respect to the same norm.